# Where should "on [date]" be put in a sentence?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, phrase-order

Which order is best, A, B, or C? I'm not sure if the date can be used in this manner.

> A. John was admitted into the University on 5 August 2013.
>
> B. On 5 August 2013, John was admitted into the University.
>
> C. John was on 5 August 2013 admitted into the University.

> A. John graduated from the University on 12 December 2018.
>
> B. On 12 December 2018, John graduated from the University.
>
> C. John graduated on 12 December 2018 from the University.

Comment: It's difficult to know the 'best word order' without knowing the importance that you attach to each part of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, grammatically, are all of them correct?

Comment: The C versions are the least acceptable, especially the first as the date splits the verb _was admitted_.

Comment: The C versions can be used if you use commas to make the prepositional phrases parenthetical: *John was, on 5 August 2013, admitted into the University*. This style reduces the emphasis on the date.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar for your reply. You added the final confirmation I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

A is my preference.

I worked as an American journalist for a short time and encountered editors who were adamant that one should never start a sentence with "on." I, on the other hand, will begin with "on" if I feel it makes the sentence more readable than other options, but I try to avoid it in general. I had editors who loved inserting as many commas as possible, so I tried to construct sentences like A to avoid the insertion of a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use A or B, like for me it sounds best. And I think that answer depends on what you want to write, like answer will be other if you are writing a letter than if you are talking with somebody.